# TFS Build stack: "F246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters..."

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have TFS 2017.3 On-Premise, with XAML builds.

We are faced with builds issues when build freezes on “Associate Changesets and Work Items” sequence with next error “**TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been canceled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct.**”

Builds with such issues aren`t stopped after the timeout, so they lock agents and build restart process.

If we re-run the build it can be passed successfully.

The issue can occur in different build definitions with different agents.

**Update:** we are facing the same issue again. the build stack on Associate Changesets and Work Items” sequence. the build machine is reverted every build so i guess clean cache is not a solution. any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we finally get RC why the build stuck.

We've looked through the history of builds, check-ins and found a specific WI from which build became stackable contains ASCII control EXT (We've just copied one by one all fields of WI to notepad++ and found that symbol (VS doesn`t show such symbols)).

After we removed this WI and created a new WI and linked the changeset to it **the build passed**.

So we guess the reason is the TFS don't know to handle this ASCII symbols and during the build he can't save the work item and the build stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to log in the build agent machine, and clean the cache folder to see whether it helps you. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.

Since you are using TFS 2017, it's suggested to switch to new build system from XAML build:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do it yesterday and we got another issue: sometimes some builds started to fail with this error: "TF30063: You are not authorized to access...", do you have any idea why? (it can fail and if we re-run it can pass)

Comment: You may try to remove the user credential in Credential Manager.

Comment: Thank you. remove and add again the credentials?

Comment: You don't need to re-add them, you'll get login request if you need any credential.

Comment: We still faced the issue of "TF30063: You are not authorized to access..." but not with the first issue, so I guess is solve this issue for now.

Comment: Update: we are facing the same issue again. the build stack on Associate Changesets and Work Items” sequence. the build machine is reverted every build so i guess clean cache is not a solution. any suggestions, please?